# Mongodb aggregate not returning results that exist

Tags: mongodb

I have a simple aggregate, like this:

```
Items.aggregate([
              {
                $limit: 1000
              },
              {
                $skip: 10000
              }
             ])
```

Which returns no results.  However, if I do a simple `Items.find({}).limit(1000).skip(10000)` this returns results.

Any ideas what I'm missing here?

Comment: Its `skip` followed by a `limit` if you are intending to do the correct thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a `find` operation, the `skip` and `limit` serve as cursor properties.

`limit` will essentially trim the results or whatever comes out of the cursor, and `skip` will move ahead by that amount.

Thus it doesn't make a difference in the order in which the two are applied. The final cursor object created is same if `limit` comes first or `skip` comes first.

If you intend to use, `skip` comes before the `limit`

```
Items.find({}).skip(10000).limit(1000)
```

However, in the case of aggregation, a strict pipeline is followed where the result of first goes into the second and so on. Thus the first `$limit` in your case will choose first 1000 docs. Then the next `$skip`
would just skip all of these 1000 docs, thus returning an empty result set. Again use `$skip` before `$limit`

```
Items.aggregate([ 
              {
                $skip: 10000
              },
              {
                $limit: 1000
              }
             ])
```